# trying to find a proper starting point as well as direction with making an app

Tags: android, xcode, eclipse

I'm trying to find the right direction and path i need to take in order to get the ball rolling in developing an android and/or iPhone app. I'm semi familiar with the SDKs and have gone over a broad assortment of texts and resources. Obviously I'm a beginner to the whole programming world, but I'm still looking for the proper direction and guidance for writing code and making this app come to fruition. my question, essentially, is where can i find proper guidance and through explanations regarding ACTUALLY making an app?

Comment: First, head on over to http://developer.android.com/ and start reading. There's a lot of good information there that can get you started. Second, you've come to the right place. Get yourself started, begin writing an app, and when you (inevitably) get stuck, ask questions. This place is full of people who want nothing more than to help out beginners, but be careful: always [ask good questions](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and [ask them in a smart way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/06/dont-ask-us-questions-well-just-ignore-you.html). Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the best tutorial

[Android Development Tutorial - Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html)